# Docker-compose up : no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker and docker-compose to run my express nodejs api.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN chmod 755 /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And as I mentioned I'm using docker-compose, here is the docker-compose.yml file content:

```
version: "3"

services:
  service:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm start
```

After running docker-compose up, I'm facing an error says it's not able to find package.json.

Here is the error:

```
service_1  | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json 
service_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT 
service_1  | npm ERR! errno -2 service_1  | npm ERR! syscall open 
service_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json' 
service_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
service_1  | npm ERR! enoent 
service_1  | 
service_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
service_1  | npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-17T07_54_07_773Z-debug.log
xuser-api_service_1 exited with code 254
```

Please help to find my mistake.

Comment: Can you include your `docker-compose.yml` in the question too?  There's a common setup that involves using `volumes:` to hide everything the Dockerfile does and it seems like that could lead to this error; if you have `volumes:` there you might try removing that block.

Comment: Hi David, I include the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

your working directory is /usr/src/app and you copied the package file on root directory .
you have to something like this

```
# set working directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install node_modules
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

# copy codebase to docker codebase
ADD . /usr/src/app
```

Comment: The `COPY` in the question is to `./`, which is the current `WORKDIR`, namely `/usr/src/app`.

Comment: you didnt add package.json into /usr/src/app, you have to add all project into your workdir

Comment: `COPY package*.json ./` should copy `package.json` (matching the glob) into `/usr/src/app` (the `WORKDIR`).

Comment: use ADD instead of copy or use RUN cp

Answer (score 1):

you may be using an old image which does not contain latest changes.
make sure you using the latest image of your docker file.

```
docker-compose build
```

then run

```
docker-compose up
```

if you doing frequent changes to Dockerfile for testing then use.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your build section to this:

```
build:
  context: MySuperAngularProject
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

In context you may set folder with your Angular project with Dockerfile